# Getting Maximum and Minimum Int instead of Input

Tags: java, loops, max, minimum

I am trying to gather input from the user, and then denote which one of their numbers is the highest, and which one is the lowest.

```
int highest = Integer.MAX_VALUE, lowest=Integer.MIN_VALUE, number=0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
       System.out.print("Enter five integers: ");
       number = input.nextInt();
    }
    if (number > highest){    
       highest = number;
    }
    if (number < lowest){
       lowest = number;
    }
    System.out.println("Your highest number is: " + highest);
    System.out.println("Your lowest number is: " + lowest);
```

It is giving me the maximum and minimum that an Integer can be ( 214... and -214...).

Comment: Move the `if` statements **inside** the loop.

Comment: You assign a value to `number` five times.  This means you are overwriting the value of `number` four times, and once you do that, the previous values are lost forever.  Your `if` statements need to be inside your loop.

Comment: The comparisons do need to be in the loop. Also, how can number be greater than highest if you initialize highest to max value?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Answer (score 1):

You should swap the highest and lowest value, a number cannot possibly be greater than highest value, highest should start with `MIN` and lowest should start with `MAX` and move the comparison inside for loop

```
int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE, lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE, number = 0;
```

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thank you! I kept thinking to switch around things but didn't realize that the min/max is what needed to be switched.

Answer (score 1):

First, make certain the prompt for five integers is `before the loop` and the input and use of the entered values are `inside the loop`.

Here are some alternatives.

1. You can also use [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#IntSummaryStatistics()). It's used quite often in stream applications but it can also be used in imperative programming.

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = new IntSummaryStatistics();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    stats.accept(input.nextInt());
}
System.out.println("Minimum = " + stats.getMin());
System.out.println("Maximum = " + stats.getMax());
```

2. Or you can use [Math.min()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,int)) and [Math.max()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,int))

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     int val = input.nextInt();
     max = Math.max(max, val);
     min = Math.min(min, val);
}
System.out.println("Minimum = " + min);
System.out.println("Maximum = " + max);
```